# How do I lock the match type from a different table from the Match Excel Formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My formula looks like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2,MATCH(SSP!C$2&SSP!$B3,Table2[ProductKey],0),4),"")
```

When I drag the formula across additional columns in Table1, the match key (i.e. the "ProductKey") changes in the formula to the next column from Table2. I know how to lock a column using f4, but that doesn't seem to work when pulling the information from another table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2,MATCH(SSP!C$2&SSP!$B3,Table2[[ProductKey]:[ProductKey]],0),4),"")
```

More details here: https://www.excelcampus.com/tips/absolute-formula-references-excel-structured-table/

Comment: Had to add an extra set of brackets around [ProductKey]:[ProductKey]; but it worked! Thanks!